# How can I check if a specific remote repository branch contains a specific merged branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I want to check if a branch on a remote Git repository contains a merged branch with a specific name. For example:

- There is a remote repository at `www.example.com:/repo.git`.
- In that repository, there are is a branch named `myBranch`.
- I want to check if a specific feature branch like `myFeatureBranch` has been merged into `myBranch`.

If I cloned the repository and checkout `myBranch`, I could do `git show-ref --verify refs/heads/myFeatureBranch`, but that's not what I want to do. I have to do it with a remote branch without cloning.

I already played around with `git ls-remote --heads www.example.com:/repo.git`, but the only thing I get is a list of remote heads. Has anyone done that before?

Comment: Doesn't the list of remote heads include the branch?

Comment: yes, but it does not specify anything about the history structure. Ie, it does not walk the DAG to that extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Git Operates Locally by Design

The distributed nature of Git is fundamentally designed around a couple of fundamental concepts:

1. Most operations are local, with a few minor exceptions like *push* and *ls-remote*.
2. History is *calculated* from commit objects.

What this means is that exploring history is a local operation, and can't be performed on a remote repository.

#### Remote References

The *git-ls-remote* command is useful in searching upstream for refs, but not for history. For example:

```
git ls-remote origin | egrep 'some_branch_name|merge'
```

will print refs on the remote that match the named branch you're looking for, or (in the case of GitHub) refs created from merged pull-requests such as:

```
381a77fd72ea594cfce5c82c845ad3d10bb87d71        refs/pull/99/merge
```

The *git-ls-remote* command displays refs available in a remote repository along with the associated commit IDs. However, if you want to find out what branch contains a given commit, you need access to the full history; that requires you to have a local copy.

#### Finding Branches Containing a Merge Commit

The best way I know to deal with this issue is the following:

1. Fetch all branches with `git fetch --all origin`.
2. Find the merge commits you want with `git log --merges`.
3. Find the containing branches with `git branch --all --contains <commit>`.

This will give you a list of branches that contain the specified commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute commands on the remote. It is simply a sync mechanism. You will need to clone to execute the regular commands.

You may want to look up `git branch -a --contains`

Comment: Thank you, that's no good news...
So I have to find another way, maybe cloning the repository on the server and then communicating via shell, or something like that. :)

Comment: You wouldn't need to reclone if you own the server. You can execute those commands on a bare repo too. But you need to ssh to that machine and execute on that machine as you say.